# ant build error: package r does not exist

Tags: java, android

I got this error message when running from command line:

```
[javac]E:\...\MainActivity.java:19: Error: Package R does not exist                      
[javac] setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I have added `import com.***.R;` to file `MainActivity.java`.
Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.***">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".JmfService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_DIR" />
</manifest>
```

I've tried `ant clean`, `rebuild project` and so on.
When clicking on the menu button to build the project, i got `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Comment: Running what from the command line? If this is an Android APK, then generally you do not "run" them from the command line - you install them into an emulator or device. If you are trying to run it as a "java" program, then the syntax used for the "R" "class" is that of "package" and it will not run.

Comment: generally when there's error in layout or drawables, R file isn't generated. make sure your layouts and drawables are fine,